# How to set with on kendoAutoComplete

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-autocomplete

I have tried every way I know how (and failed) to properly set the width on a `kendoAutoComplete`. My latest attempt (below) is JS based, but I've also tried numerous CSS solutions.

The issue I'm seeing is that no matter the width I choose, the actual input area remains a consistent width, and then there is a weird gray area to the right:

[image]

Here's the hover state (the gray box disappears):

[image]

But don't be fooled by the appearance of a large text box. Here's what happens when you begin to type:

[image]

I've tried:

```
var autoComplete = $("#gridFilter").data("kendoAutoComplete");
autoComplete.list.width(400);
```

And

```
autoComplete .wrapper.css("width", "300px");
```

And...various CSS solutions.

Why must it be so hard to set the width of a silly auto complete? What am I missing here?

I want the width of my auto complete to be 100% to fill its container.

**Bonus points if you can help me understand why Telerik consistently makes me want to hurt myself.**

**EDIT**

OK, I've (partially) figured it out. I temporarily removed bootstrap CSS from the page and the input works as expected.

If I find the offending CSS, I'll post an answer here.

Comment: How did you set it up? Is it any different than the 100% width kendoAutoComplete [in this example](http://dojo.telerik.com/IHOji)?

Comment: I see no difference whatsoever.

Comment: _"Why Telerik consistently makes me want to hurt myself?"_ Because with great features comes great ... At this exacty moment Uncle Ben was shoot, by him self. To fix this, try to transphorm or redirect your anger to them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the edit above, default Bootstrap CSS was conflicting with the styling. Specifically, the `max-width` property. The CSS below fixed it:

```
<input id="gridFilter" style="max-width: 10000px; width:100%;" />
```

Comment: This is awsome! Thanks!